# Null/0 Answers Not Appearing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Another Question for Today :)

Wrote a query that works perfectly - except I want it to show NULL/0 values as 0 - and - that isn't happening.  I tried approaching this two ways:

First I used `isnull()`

```
Select isnull(Count(*),0) as Total ,
       z.zname
From STable   s   ,
     SLTable  sl  ,
     ZTable   z   ,
     SETable  se  , 
     SEETable see ,
     SEGTable seg
Where s.sID     = sl.sID
  and sl.zID    = z.zID
  and s.sID     = se.sID
  and se.etID   = see.etID
  and see.segID = seg.segID
  and see.segID = 3
Group By z.zname
order by z.zname
```

Is doesn't seem to give me the Null/0 values

Then I tried using a sum/case approach

```
Select sum(case when see.segID <> 3 then 0 else 1 end) as Total ,
       z.zname
From STable    s   ,
     SLTable   sl  ,
      Table    z   ,
      SETable  se  ,
      SEETable see ,
      SEGTable seg
Where s.sID     = sl.sID
  and sl.zID    = z.zID
  and s.sID     = se.sID
  and se.etID   = see.etID
  and see.segID = seg.segID
  and see.segID = 3
Group By z.zname
order by z.zname
```

And still no 0 values - so now I'm stumped :(

Comment: So you don't want it to count where it is null or 0?

Comment: And null/0 of what column?

Comment: Perhaps Your INNER Joins may need to turn into outer joins otherwise the joins will exclude records you may be wanting to see.  So do you want to see all records in stable and only those in SL, Z, Se and see and seg that match or only if a record exists in all tables? (which is why you're not seeing 0's as you're seeing only those that have matches in all of em) visual explanation of joins http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's unclear what you're actually trying to find. However, a big part of your problem is  that you're using old-school, pre-ISO/ANSI `join` syntax. If you refactor your join to use modern `join` syntax, you'll get a query that looks somethinn (a lot, actually) like this:

```
select zName = z.zname  , 
       Total = count(*)
From ZTable   z   
join SLTable  sl  on sl.zID    = z.zID
join STable   s   on s.sID     = sl.sID
join SETable  se  on se.sID    = s.sID
join SEETable see on see.etID  = se.etID
                 and see.segID = 3
join SEGTable seg on seg.segID = see.segID
Group By z.zname
order by z.zname
```

I suspect that what you want to get is a list of *all* `zNames` and their respect counts of having `segID = 3`. Since you are using *inner* joins, you'll only ever see `zNames` that have a match. What you can do is something like this:

```
select zName = z.zname  , 
       Total = sum(case see.segID when 3 then 1 else 0 end)
from      ZTable   z   
left join SLTable  sl  on sl.zID   = z.zID
left join STable   s   on s.sID    = sl.sID
left join SETable  se  on se.sID   = s.sID
left join SEETable see on see.etID = se.etID
group By z.zname
order by z.zname
```

The above will return *every* row from `zTable` at least once, with `null` values for the columns of any table for which no match was found. Then we group it and count the rows where `segID` is 3.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and it worked perfectly - I'll have to keep in mind the various joins for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Actually just to semi answer my own question - just realized that where - see.segID-3 - so it'll only turn out results with segID = 3 - so it cannot NOT have 3 - right?

But Im specifically looking for segIDs as 3 - just, if there is nothing there then display 0

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am assuming you need changed

```
Select 
Count(*) as Total,
z.zname
From STable s, SLTable sl, ZTable z, SETable se, SEETable see, SEGTable seg
Where s.sID=sl.sID
and sl.zID=z.zID
and s.sID=se.sID
and se.etID=see.etID
and see.segID=seg.segID
and see.segID=3
AND TABLE.YOURCOLUMN IS NOT NULL       -- THESE ARE 
AND TABLE.YOURCOLUMN <> 0              -- NEW
GROUP BY z.zname
ORDER BY z.zname
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Query
isnull(Count(*),0) as Total,

Count will never return null, it will be numeric values ranging from 0 to n.

So your isnull condition will never get satisfy.

You can simply write select count(*) as total .. instead of isnull(Count(*),0) and it will return 0 when ever it will find no rows in table.